# Constrained optimization in R with constraints on result

Tags: r, optimization, mathematical-optimization

I am attempting to optimize a function in R that has constraints on the input parameters, but also constraints on a result in the function. I am using constrOptim.

The function I have to optimize is below:

```
  fn.opt <- function(x){
    fnLambda=x[[1]]
    fnSigma=x[[2]]

    fn.norm = fnLambda*dnorm(pz$x, mean=mxMu, sd=fnSigma)

    fn.res = sum((density$y - fn.norm)^2)

    return(fn.res)
  }
```

Here I have a kernel density estimate `density` of some data, and I have a normal approximation `fn.norm`. I would like to minimize the sum of squared residuals, which this successfully does using constrOptim.

```
        theta = c(mxLambda,mxSigma)
        ui = rbind(c(1,0),c(-1,0),c(0,1))
        ci = c(0,-1,0)
        pz.opt = constrOptim(theta=theta,f=fn.opt,ui=ui,ci=ci,grad=NULL)
        pz.opt
```

Constraints: 0 <= mxLambda <=1 & 0< mxSigma

However I would also like the normal density approximation `fn.norm` to be strictly less than the density of the data `density$y`.

Is there any way I could add in a constraint that has `fn.norm < density$y` while still optimizing `fn.res`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are not using mxLambda in the function : fn.opt.